# Accessing the listview from onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview

In the shopping cart activity I have a `listview` and I have placed a `imagebutton` on top of it as shown in the `class_list_group.xml`. When start of the activity I want to hide the `imagebutton`. But once press the edit button in the action bar (`onOptionsItemSelected` in the activity class) I want to display a relative layout which is carrying the `imagebutton` as shown in the xml file.

That is my question, my problem is how can I do it? any help will be appreciated. It crahses from what I have done saying null point exception.

**Shoppingcartactivity.java class**

```
    public class ShoppingCartActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView totalTV;
    private TextView discountTV;
    private TextView totalExclTV;
    private TextView totalTaxTV;
    private TextView netPriceTV;
    private ProductAdapter mProductAdapter;
    private ExpandableListView expListView;
    private EditText couponET;
    private ImageButton couponBTN;
    private List<Product> mCartList;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
    private String Strdiscount;
    private double discount;
    public JSONObject DiscountObj;
    private double addSubTotal;
    RelativeLayout hiddenEditDelete;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cart_activity);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        getActionBar().setIcon(
                new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(
                        android.R.color.transparent)));
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
        // Enabling Back navigation on Action Bar icon
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mCartList = ShoppingCartHelper.getCartList();

        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
        mProductAdapter = new ProductAdapter(this, mCartList,
                getLayoutInflater(), true);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(mProductAdapter);

        totalTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total_valueamount);
        discountTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.discount_valueamount);
        totalExclTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.exl_tax_valueamount);
        totalTaxTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ttl_tax_valueamount);
        netPriceTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.net_price_valueamount);
        couponBTN = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btncoupon);
        couponET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_coupon);
        hiddenEditDelete = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_cartedit);
        hiddenEditDelete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        couponET.setEnabled(false);
        couponBTN.setEnabled(false);
        priceCalculation();

        double taxamount = (addSubTotal * 5) / 100;
        double netTotal = addSubTotal + taxamount;

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

        addSubTotal = Double.valueOf(df.format(addSubTotal));
        taxamount = Double.valueOf(df.format(taxamount));
        netTotal = Double.valueOf(df.format(netTotal));

        totalTV.setText(Double.toString(addSubTotal));
        discountTV.setText("0.0");
        totalExclTV.setText(Double.toString(addSubTotal));
        totalTaxTV.setText(Double.toString(taxamount));
        netPriceTV.setText(Double.toString(netTotal));



//      couponBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//          public void onClick(View v) {
//
//              try {
//                  String CouponCode = couponET.getText().toString();
//
//                  if (!Utility.isNotNull(CouponCode)) {
//                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
//                              "Insert coupon code", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                  } else {
//                      new CouponAsyncTask(ShoppingCartActivity.this)
//                              .execute(CouponCode);
//                  }
//              } catch (Exception e) {
//                  e.printStackTrace();
//              }
//          }
//      });

    }

    public void loadCouponData() {

        Strdiscount = DiscountObj.optString("Discount");
        try {
            Log.i("Discount", DiscountObj.getString("Discount"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void priceCalculation() {

        for (int i = 0; i < mCartList.size(); i++) {

            if (!mCartList.isEmpty()) {
                couponET.setEnabled(true);
                couponBTN.setEnabled(true);
            }
            Product cat = mCartList.get(i);
            addSubTotal += cat.subTotal;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_cart, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Take appropriate action for each action item click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left,
                    R.anim.slide_out_right);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_edit:
            hiddenEditDelete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right,
                    R.anim.slide_out_left);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

**class_list_group.xml class**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/shareLILayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:weightSum="5" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="28dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_cartedit"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btneditcartitem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:src="@drawable/edititem" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ProductAdapter .java**

```
public class ProductAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private List<Product> mCartList;
    private Context _context;
    private List<Product> _cartList;
    private boolean mShowQuantity;

    public ProductAdapter(Context context, List<Product> cartList,
            LayoutInflater inflater, boolean showQuantity) {
        this._context = context;
        this._cartList = cartList;
        mShowQuantity = showQuantity;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return _cartList.get(groupPosition).getItems().get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return _cartList.get(groupPosition).getItems().get(childPosition)
                .hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_list_item, parent, false);
        }

        TextView itemSize = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblListItemSize);

        Item det = _cartList.get(groupPosition).getItems().get(childPosition);

        itemSize.setText(det.itemName + " ( " + det.price + " ) ");

        mCartList = ShoppingCartHelper.getCartList();

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        int size = _cartList.get(groupPosition).getItems().size();
        System.out.println("Child for group [" + groupPosition + "] is ["
                + size + "]");
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._cartList.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._cartList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_list_group, parent, false);
        }

        TextView groupName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        TextView groupQty = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lbl_qty);
        TextView groupSubtotal = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblsubtotal);

        final Product cat = _cartList.get(groupPosition);

//      ShoppingCartEntry catalog = ShoppingCartHelper.getByProduct(cat);
//      int productIndex = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(
//              ShoppingCartHelper.PRODUCT_INDEX);
//      final Product selectedProduct = catalog.get(productIndex);


        groupName.setText(cat.description);
        groupQty.setText(String.valueOf(cat.quantity));
        groupSubtotal.setText(Double.toString(cat.subTotal));

        ImageButton editIB = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btneditcartitem);

        if (cat.itemCategory != null && cat.itemCategory.equals("Pizza"))
            editIB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent next = new Intent(_context, ActivityEdit.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putDouble("subTotal", cat.subTotal);
                next.putExtras(b);
                next.putExtra("description", cat.description);

                _context.startActivity(next);
                ((Activity) _context).overridePendingTransition(
                        R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
            }
        });


        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

**cart_Activity**

```
 <ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/lvExp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="162dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/grid_topics"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:groupIndicator="@drawable/group_indicator" >
</ExpandableListView>
```

[image]

Comment: why don't you use `.setVisibility(View.)` ?

Comment: I have used this in my activity  hiddenEditDelete.setVisibility(View.GONE);. but result in crashing

Comment: Show the crash report.

Comment: this is the line 79, where it crashes. hiddenEditDelete.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: `hiddenEditDelete` is your in `class_list_group.xml`  not in a `cart_activity`. This cause a null pointer exception.

Comment: I know that, my problem is how to access the how to access the onOptionsItemSelected from adapter class or the activity class

Comment: You can inflate that view for your Action bar. Means you need to set a custom view for action bar.

Comment: Do u mind helping me with code level because I have no idea how to do what u have said. or give me example to look at it and try

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized `hiddenEditDelete` before using it in the `onCreate` method and that's why NPE is thrown. Also, I believe `setContentView` should be called last

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
      mProductAdapter = new ProductAdapter(this, mCartList,
            getLayoutInflater(), true);

      expListView.setAdapter(mProductAdapter);

      hiddenEditDelete = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_cartedit);
      hiddenEditDelete.setVisibility(View.GONE);

      setContentView(R.layout.cart_activity);
   }
```

Comment: invoke `setContenView` at the end of the method

Comment: still the same result. bro is it possible to access listview items from the main activity? i think problem is something with that. When run the app without  use of hiddenEditDelete line it works.

Comment: would you add `cart_activity` xml code into your question?

Comment: I have just a list view this id, lvExp

Comment: It would be difficult to help you if we don't see the code, also I just noticed that `expListView`, `mProductAdapter ` and `mCartList` are not declared in you activity, so I am wondering how this code builds, furthermore even if it could be build, `mCartList` should be `null` hence your adapter would throw NPE

Comment: I have updated, everything is working fine only problem is how to access the onOptionsItemSelected from adapter classs

Comment: Why do you need to access it from the adapter? What exactly do you want to achieve, I understood that you want the image to be shown once 'edit menu item' is clicked, but where and how this image is expected to be displayed, should it be all over the screen, or position over/bellow some item of the list view?

Comment: there is a xml file in my question, class_list_group in that i Have a RelativeLayout with the id rl_cartedit. I want to show/hide that layout. that is ontop of listview. (it will come to each line of the listview)

Comment: Let's see if I understand you correctly: You have an expandable list view containing items that are divided in viewgroups, when the user clicks `Edit`  from the action bar menu, you want the image in `rl_cartedit` to be shown over each view group?

Comment: yeh.. thats  a edit image so user can select items from the list view

Comment: I think the approach to this behavior is incorrect, firstly, you can't access `rl_cartedit` directly from the activity, because you inflate each listview item with it, so there are so many of it. Each listview item individually should set the visibility to its child relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you haven't took any reference for hiddenEditDelete (like expListView) before accessing it , You have to instantiate it with the proper layout id before using it. Then and then you can do whatever you want with the layout. Everything else is correct in onCreate()

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cart_activity);

    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
mProductAdapter = new ProductAdapter(this, mCartList,
        getLayoutInflater(), true);

expListView.setAdapter(mProductAdapter);

    hiddenEditDelete.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}
```

Comment: Ok i understood that. So can u tell me what should I add in my onCreate()?

Comment: write this in on create before accestting the layout                     hiddenEditDelete=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(YOUR_XML_ID);

Comment: I have this line hiddenEditDelete = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_cartedit);

Comment: Then it should work. Can you please provide stack trace of the error?

Comment: Can you please check **rl_cartedit** is avaialble in your **cart_activity** xml ?

Comment: I have cart_activity.xml, inside that I have a expandable listview called lvExp. I'm trying to use hiddenEditDelete inside that listview. SO i dnt have rl_cartedit  in cart activity

Comment: That's the problem. You cant use **rl_cartedit** in your activity. Use it in class where you are using **class_list_group**

Comment: I have this ProductAdapter .java. i think i need to use it inside here but then my problem is how can I access the onOptionsItemSelected in the activity from the adapter.